# How to convert matlab code to python code?

Tags: python, matlab

I need my Matlab code to convert to Python code. You can see my attempt below. It produces the following error in the 'H_sel' part:

> Error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Matlab code:

```
 % system-parameters
 Nt = 16;
 Nr = 16;

 % 1. conversion SNRdB to Linear
 SNRdB = 10;
 SNR= 10^(SNRdB/10);

 % 2. number to array
 Nr = 16;
 fully_Nr = (1:Nr);

 % 3. Rayleigh fading channel matrix
 H = sqrt(1/2)*(randn(Nr,Nt)+1j*randn(Nr,Nt));

 % 4. generate selected channel matrix
 H_sel=H((1:Nr),:);

 % 5. Selected channel capacity
 capacity=log2(det(eye(Nt)+SNR/Nt*(H_sel'*H_sel)));
```

Converted to Python:

```
 # system-parameters
 import numpy as np
 Nt = 16
 Nr = 16
 
 # 1. conversion SNRdB to Linear
 SNRdB = 10
 SNR = 10 ** (SNRdB / 10)

 # 2. number to array
 Nr = 16
 fully_Nr = (np.arange(1,Nr+1))
 
 # 3. Rayleigh fading channel matrix (transmit, receive antennas)
 H = np.sqrt(1 / 2) * (np.random.randn(Nr,Nt) + 1j * np.random.randn(Nr,Nt))
 
 # 4. generate selected channel matrix (error line!!!!!!!)
 H_sel = H((np.arange(1,Nr+1)),:)
 
 # 5. Selected channel capacity
 capacity = np.log2(np.linalg.det(np.eye(Nt) + SNR / Nt * (np.transpose(H_sel) * H_sel)))
 print(capacity)
```

Comment: Python uses zero-based indexing and uses the square brackets `[]` for indexing/slicing. Matlab uses one-based indexing and parenthesis `()` for indexing/slicing. The slice semantics are also different. Python slices don't include the end point whereas Matlab does. You'll need to account for these difference (and others) when translating this code.

Comment: Specifically I'm guessing you want `H_sel = H[:Nr,:]`. Also, in numpy `*` means element-wise multiply (equivalent to `.*` in Matlab). Use either `np.dot`, `np.matmul` or the `@` operator for matrix multiplication in numpy (`dot` and `matmul`/`@` have different broadcast semantics but I think they would all work the same here).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, actually I am not familiar with the python language and stack-overflow platform. Thank you for your help.